# How to find a text and get the line number from acrobat using vba

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I am Trying to find a text from PDF file and get all the words associated with that line in excel. Obtained some syntax from website that will read PDF word by word and locate the matched text and get the next word, but my problem with this approach is values next to matched text varies, it could be either single or multiple words to be captured.
example:

> Printed By: Arun Ragavan
>   Printed By: Arun

Here I want to get text next to "Printed By:" sometimes its one word "Arun" and some time its two words "Arun Ragavan"; so I am trying to locate the line number and get the complete text in excel.

Code Tried:

```
Set avobj = pddoc.OpenAVDoc(DocName)
Set jso = pddoc.GetJSObject
cntPages = pddoc.GetNumPages
    For ip = 0 To cntPages - 1
        cntWords = jso.getPageNumWords(ip)
        For iw = 0 To cntWords - 1
            If jso.getPageNthWord(ip, iw) = "By" Then
                ws.Range("A1").Value = jso.getPageNthWord(ip, iw + 1) & jso.getPageNthWord(ip, iw + 2)
            End If
         Next
    Next
```

Like the above example I have many other fields to be extracted by finding the text.

Comment: Do you use a specific library to read the pdf documents?

Comment: Yes I use Acrobat standard

Comment: I mean VBA library, I cannot run your code unless I add the library

Comment: Adobe Acrobat 9.0 library iam using to use jso

Comment: weird! I cannot see such a library on my end, I am using Excel 2010, can you add a screenshot to see what exactly you are using VBE > Tools > References

Comment: Library visible only if u have installed Acrobat standard version in pc

Comment: Sorry! I cannot run the code then!

Comment: @yivi wow! thanks for your edit